# Windows 10 apps in fullscreen mode by default

Tags: windows-10-preview, fullscreen, windows-store-app

In Windows 10 Technical Preview, the "Modern apps" now starts in windowed mode by default. Is there any option to make the apps start in fullscreen mode by default?

Comment: A way to do this won't be introduced, if its introduced, until a future release based on my research

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since the release of build 9926 it is now possible to make all apps run in fullscreen mode by switching to tablet mode in your quick settings/notification center.

this will however lock all apps to their "windows 8.1" behavior, as well as lock the start menu in its "start screen" mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can full-screen any 'Modern UI app' using Win+Shift+Enter keys.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. As of Windows Technical Preview build 9860 all modern apps will launch in a maximised window with a title bar. These can be set to full screen by clicking on the "..." button on the title bar but these settings are not persistent so will revert to maximised window the next time you start the app.

Answer (score -3):

**Find the Personalize settings. 
Mouse Right click >  Personalize > Start > Use Start full screen > Off/On  .**

When you press the windows Icon, the desktop will fade, and all apps will be enlarged across the entire screen.

..Windows 10 Build version 10240 .

As mentioned above ; the other way to do this, is by pressing the 
**Notifications icon** ,**on the task bar**, found to the far right corner  ; it looks like a **Squared speech bubble ; press that > Tablet Mode** will then be seen . Once on , **whenever you press the windows icon, say on a desk top, it will show all apps full screen enlarged.**